# Mouse Over for all fields without using onmouserover option

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm Working on an application in asp.net in which mouseover should be implemented for all fields, labels and grid view headers. I tried to implement it by using onmouserover option or by using jquery function function mouseover but in this i have to write that function for each in every field. I want to know whether there is a better way to implement this so that we can write only one function which can be called every time when ever mouseover happens. Can any one suggest best way to implement this. I will get the data that has to be displayed for mouseover events from database that is data is stored in a table format which contains field names and the corresponding description that has to be displayed in case of mouseover

Comment: If you show your html markup that would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can write `mouseover` once for all those required fields:

```
$('input,label,span,.para').mouseover(function () {

    if ($(this).is('input')) 
      $('#res').text($(this).val());
    if ($(this).is('label') || $(this).is('span') || $(this).is('div')) 
      $('#res').text($(this).text());

});
```

You can also use css class in the list of selectors like *para* in above example.

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/BLfJ8/)**

In demo, type something in textbox then place your mouse over it.

Comment: Will above mentioned code work for asp.net pages? I have seen demo in that this is applied for html code but will this work for asp.net labels and other fields ?

Comment: Yes it will work for asp.net too, asp.net controls are rendered as html controls in browser like asp.net's _textbox_ is rendered as html _input type="text"_, asp.net's _gridview_ as html _table_ etc., you can see your page's generated html source in browser then you can modify above code as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a handler that would loop through all the controls on the page during the loading (be sure to do early enough that the events will still get registered) and add the events based on the control type.

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if(c.GetType() == typeof(Label)) // Probably not correct syntax, but you get idea
    {
        //*cast your control
        c.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "yourJScriptEvent");
    }
    else if (...)
}
```